# C# - Get byte position of MediaElement

Tags: c#, mediaelement

Basically, I want to get the current byte of the MediaElement at its current playback position. For example, when it is at 5 seconds, the byte position would be 1024kb. I don't want to multiply the bitrate with the current time as that is not accurate.

All I need is to get the byte position at certain durations.

So is there anyway I could get this? I'm open to other options. (Does FFProbe support this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried everything and there is no way to do this directly using MediaElement.

The only way is to get the frame number of the video by multiplying the framerate with the timecode of the byte position you want to get.

Then use a program like [BmffViewer](https://github.com/jeremypoulter/basemedia/tree/master/BMFF/BmffViewer) which analyzes the moov atom of the video header. Then go to the stco entries of the track you want to analyze and get the chunk offset of the frame you calculated earlier.